# How to determine which glibc function is called from binary?

Tags: binaryfiles, elf

Is there any way we could say which glibc function is called from ARM elf binary?  For example, consider the following diassembly:

```
8300 <printf@plt-0x40>:
   ....
8320:   e28fc600    add ip, pc, #0, 12
8324:   e28cca08    add ip, ip, #8, 20  ; 0x8000
8328:   e5bcf344    ldr pc, [ip, #836]! ; 0x344

   ....
83fc <main>:
   ...
8424:ebffffbd   bl  8320 <_init+0x2c>
```

Here, how we can say that bl 8320 is a call to printf?  Is this information stored in ELF binary somewhere?

Comment: Does that binary still have a symbol table or was it stripped (`-s` at link time)? What does `nm a.out` report?

Comment: both symbol table and dynamic symbol are present. nm reports all the symbols in the binary.  Is there a way?

Comment: If really *all* symbols, even printf, are in the a.out, then you have a statically linked binary and there is probably no way to determine which symbol came from a specific library other than making a list of symbols for each library and compare the list to the symbols in the a.out.

Comment: I mean, printf is in dynamic symbol table. Binary is dynamically linked.  All I want to know is  which library routine "bl 8310" is actually calling through plt?..  There should be some information in the binary about this, otherwise how would dynamic linker will know which routine to invoke at runtime?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way we could say which glibc function is called from ARM elf binary?

Not really.

You could trivially ask "what *external* functions are called by a binary", like so:

```
nm -D a.out | grep ' U '
```

*Which library* the undefined functions are defined in is *not* recorded, and can in fact change. For example, you could use `LD_PRELOAD=libfoo.so` to inject a different `printf` defined in `libfoo.so`, and preempt the `glibc` definition of `printf`.

Comment: Ok. But in that case, how the disassembler was able to identify the fact that it is a call to printf?  It clearly displays 8300 <printf@plt-0x40>:  in the beginning.

Comment: Actuallly also when .plt calls dynamic linker, how the linker knows  which library routine is invoked?

Comment: @VasantK Well, the point of a symbol table is to give names to numbers. There's no magic here. The disassembler knows that this is a call to printf because the symbol table maps that address to the printf symbol. Strip the symbol table and the disassembler will no longer show the printf, only the number.

Comment: I thought that too. Dynamic symbol table should map the address to symbol.  But symbols in dynsym have value of 0 . I have a posted a question here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32737355/elf-dynamic-symbol-table.  Please have a look.

Comment: Well you can't strip the (dynamic) symbol table otherwise the PLT won't work in the first place…

Answer (score 1):

TLDR: You have to compute the address of the GOT entry (stored in IP but the PLT) and find the relocation entry corresponding to this GOT entry. This relocation entry references the symbol name (through the dynamic symbol table and the dynamic string table).

### Your example

This PLT entry computes the address of a PLTGOT entry in the IP register:

```
8320:   e28fc600    add ip, pc, #0, 12
8324:   e28cca08    add ip, ip, #8, 20  ; 0x8000
8328:   e5bcf344    ldr pc, [ip, #836]! ; 0x344
```

This computes the GOT entry of address: 0x8320 + 0x8 + 0x8000 + 0x344 = 0x1066c. There is a relocation entry in the relocation table which binds this GOT entry to a given symbol.

### Another example

Let's take this PLT entry from my libc:

```
00015b98 :
   15b98:       e28fc601        add     ip, pc, #1048576        ; 0x100000
   15b9c:       e28cca2f        add     ip, ip, #192512 ; 0x2f000
   15ba0:       e5bcf46c        ldr     pc, [ip, #1132]!        ; 0x46c
```

The address of the GOT entry is: 0x15b98 + 0x8 + 0x100000 + 0x2f000 + 0x46c = 0x14500c.

If you want to know why "+ 0x8", this is [because](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0473e/Cacdbfji.html):

> In ARM state, the value of the PC is the address of the current
>   instruction plus 8 bytes.

Let's look at the relocation entry:

```
 Offset     Info    Type            Sym.Value  Sym. Name
0014500c  0001e416 R_ARM_JUMP_SLOT   00077c28   realloc
```

So this PLT entry is a PLT to `realloc` which is what we expected to get! \o/

### Findinf the symbol name

You might want to know how the symbol name is found. In my example, the info field is 0x0001e416: this relocation uses the symbol entry 0x1e4 = 484 in the dynamic symbol table (`.dynsym`)

```
   Num:    Value  Size Type    Bind   Vis      Ndx Name
   484: 00077c28   760 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   11 realloc@@GLIBC_2.4
```

In fact, the `realloc` string is not found in the symbol table directly but in the string table (`.dynstr`). The symbol table stores the offset of the string within the string table.