# How the dynamic linker determines which routine to call on Linux?

Tags: linker, elf, dynamic-linking, binaries

I have a question about dynamic linking on Linux. Consider the following disassembly of an ARM binary.

```
8300 <printf@plt-0x40>:
     ....
8320:   e28fc600    add ip, pc, #0, 12
8324:   e28cca08    add ip, ip, #8, 20  ; 0x8000
8328:   e5bcf344    ldr pc, [ip, #836]! ; 0x344
     ....
83fc <main>:
    ...
8424:ebffffbd   bl  8320 <_init+0x2c>
```

Main function calls printf at 8424: bl 8320.  8320 is an address in the .plt shown above. Now the code in .plt makes call to dynamic linker to invoke printf routine. My question is how the dynamic linker will be able to say that it is a call to printf?

Comment: This is highly similar to your previous question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32749328/how-to-determine-which-glibc-function-is-called-from-binary).

Answer (score 2):

TLDR; The PLT calls the dynamic linker by passing:

- the address of the GOT entry in IP (`&PLTGOT[n+3]`);
- `&PLTGOT[2]` is in LR;

Moreover `PLTGOT[1]` identifies the shared-object/executable.

The dynamic linker use this to find the relocation entry (`plt_relocation_table[n]`) and thus the symbol (`printf`).

### Explanation of the PLT entry code

This is explained (somehow) in [section A.3 of ELF for ARM](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ihi0044e/IHI0044E_aaelf.pdf#page45):

```
8320:   e28fc600    add ip, pc, #0, 12
8324:   e28cca08    add ip, ip, #8, 20  ; 0x8000
8328:   e5bcf344    ldr pc, [ip, #836]! ; 0x344
```

Which are explained by:

```
ADD   ip, pc, #-8:PC_OFFSET_27_20:__PLTGOT(X)
     ; R_ARM_ALU_PC_G0_NC(__PLTGOT(X))
ADD ip, ip, #-4:PC_OFFSET_19_12: __PLTGOT(X)
     ;R_ARM_ALU_PC_G1_NC(__PLTGOT(X))
LDR   pc, [ip, #0:PC_OFFSET_11_0:__PLTGOT(X)]!
     ; R_ARM_LDR_PC_G2(__PLTGOT(X))
```

Those instructions do two things:

- they compute the address of the GOT entry as an offset from PC and store it in the IP register;
- they jump to this GOT entry.

The spec notes that:

> The write-back on the final LDR ensures that ip contains
>   the address of the PLTGOT entry. This is critical to
>   incremental dynamic linking.

The "write-back" is the use of "!" in the last instruction: this is used to update IP register with the final offset (#836). This way IP contains the addess of the GOT entry at the end of the PLT entry.

The dynamic linker has the address of the GOT entry in IP:

- it can find the shared-object or executable;
- it can find the correct relocation entry.

This relocation entry references the symbol of target function (`printf` in your case):

```
Offset    Info     Type              Sym. Value Sym. Name
0001066c  00000116 R_ARM_JUMP_SLOT   00000000   printf
```

The [Base Platform ABI for the ARM architecture](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ihi0037c/IHI0037C_bpabi.pdf) notes that:

> When the platform supports lazy function binding (as ARM Linux does)
>   this ABI requires ip to address the corresponding 
>   PLTGOT entry at the point where the PLT calls through it.
>   (The  PLT is requir ed to behave as if it ended with  LDR pc, [ip]).

### Finding the relocation entry from the GOT

Now the way the relocation entry is found from the GOT address is not clear. Binary search could be used but is would not be convenient. The GNU ld.so does it like this (glibc/sysdeps/arm/dl-trampoline.S):

```
dl_runtime_resolve:
        cfi_adjust_cfa_offset (4)
        cfi_rel_offset (lr, 0)

        @ we get called with
        @       stack[0] contains the return address from this call
        @       ip contains &GOT[n+3] (pointer to function)
        @       lr points to &GOT[2]

        @ Save arguments.  We save r4 to realign the stack.
        push    {r0-r4}
        cfi_adjust_cfa_offset (20)
        cfi_rel_offset (r0, 0)
        cfi_rel_offset (r1, 4)
        cfi_rel_offset (r2, 8)
        cfi_rel_offset (r3, 12)

        @ get pointer to linker struct
        ldr     r0, [lr, #-4]

        @ prepare to call _dl_fixup()
        @ change &GOT[n+3] into 8*n        NOTE: reloc are 8 bytes each
        sub     r1, ip, lr
        sub     r1, r1, #4
        add     r1, r1, r1
[...]
```

1. The address of the second GOT entry is in LR. I guess this is donebyt `.PLT0`:

   ```
   00015b84 :
    15b84:       e52de004        push    {lr}            ; (str lr, [sp, #-4]!)
    15b88:       e59fe004        ldr     lr, [pc, #4]    ; 15b94 
    15b8c:       e08fe00e        add     lr, pc, lr
    15b90:       e5bef008        ldr     pc, [lr, #8]!
    15b94:       0012f46c        andseq  pc, r2, ip, ror #8
   ```
2. From those two GOT addresses, the dynamic linker can find the GOT offset and the offset in the PLT relocation table.
3. From `&GOT[2]`, the dynamic linker can find the second entry of the PLTGOT (`GOT[1]`) which contains the address of the linker struct (a reference used by the dynamic linker to recosgnise this shared-object/executable).

I don't where this is specified: it does not seem to be part of the base ARM ABI spec.

Answer (score 1):

`.rela.plt` contains the address of printf to inform the dynamic linker from where to locate the printf

check this link for details very soft to digest https://www.technovelty.org/linux/plt-and-got-the-key-to-code-sharing-and-dynamic-libraries.html. This article also clarify about process of variables to be accessed through Shared libraries first and then functions.

Answer (score 1):

The process of dynamic linking is described in great detail [here](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/08/25/load-time-relocation-of-shared-libraries/).

TL;DR: at static link time, `ld` creates a set of tables in special sections such as `.rel.dyn`, `.rel.plt`, etc., which tell the runtime loader what to do at runtime.

You can examine these tables with `nm -D`, `readelf -Wr`, `objdump -R`, etc.

Comment: but I think .rel.dyn is used only for variables but not for functions. "dynamic" functions goes in .rel.plt